# Part of input string to match with arraylist string

Tags: c#, string, linq, arraylist, c#-4.0

How to matches the string in a sentence with the array list string

Input - *Machine Name is server1.domain.com*

ArrayList of string - *server1.domain.com*, *server2.domain.com*, *server3.domain.com*

I want to return true if `server1.domain.com` is found in the list that is matched with the part of the given input.

I have checked many examples and they all have provided as `ArrayList.Contains(....)`, but that is not required and it is vice-versa.

if it is not an array, I can code like below and get my desired return value.

```
var serverName = "Machine Name is server1.domain.com";
serverName.Contains("server1.domain.com");
```

But, for an array / list, how can I get my desired return value.

Thank You

Comment: By the way, no experienced C# programmer has used the ArrayList type in nearly 20 years. What do you mean by _"but that is not required and it is vice-versa."_?

Comment: It means how to use array in place of the following code - "server1.domain.com". `serverName.Contains("server1.domain.com");` like `serverName.Contains(serverList.Select(x => x));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the server names in an array, then you can loop over that array, and check whether one of the array elements is contained in the input string:

```
var input = "Machine Name is server1.domain.com";
var serverNames = new [] { "server1.domain.com", "server2.domain.com", "server3.domain.com" };

var found = false;
foreach (var serverName in serverNames)
{
    if (input.Contains(serverName))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use Linq instead of the foreach loop:

```
var found = serverNames.Any(serverName => input.Contains(serverName));
```

Note: if you want the comparison to be case-insensitive, then use
`string.Contains(serverName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` instead.

See here for an example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CiVgqd

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ to check is even better with the method Any where you check if any of the element in the Array contains the input string

```
//the input string 
var input = "server1.domain.com";
//the array holding the lost of server names
var serverNames = new [] { "server1.domain.com", "server2.domain.com", "server3.domain.com" };
//use LINQ to check 
if(serverNames.Any(x=>input.Contains(x)){
//TO DO 
}
```